# Wordpress/OptimizePress redirect wp-login.php in my new login form

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I created a new login form and I would like to keep this.
Wordpress, however, sends me back to wp-login.php while I would like to keep it on "https://www.matteofeduzi.com/accedi"

[This is my new login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpvix.png)

Can anyone help me please?

The objectives to which this form must fulfill are:

1) Log in correctly (anyone who wants can try signing up "sign up").

2) At the wrong login remain on the page: "https://www.matteofeduzi.com/accedi" and maybe even show an error message.

Currently I am using this code but it does not allow me to login with the right credentials:

```
add_action('init','custom_login');
function custom_login(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow && $_GET['action']!="logout") {
    wp_redirect('https://www.matteofeduzi.com/accedi/');
    exit();
  }
}
```

Best regards.